# Random name generator for objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a name for each Goblin object, but either they all have the same name or this error happens

```py
import random

max_enemies = 5


class Entity():
    def __init__(self, name, max_hp, min_hp, attack_dmg):
        self.name = name
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.min_hp = min_hp
        attack_dmg = attack_dmg

class Goblin(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


Enemies = []


def enemy_spawner():
    for x in range(max_enemies):
        random_name_gen = random.randint(1, 10)
        Enemies.append(Goblin(random_name_gen))

enemy_spawner()

for x in range(len(Enemies)):
    print(Goblin.name)
```

The error

> AttributeError: type object 'Goblin' has no attribute 'name'

I've tried making Goblin it's own class with a name but it didn't work either

Comment: So *sometimes* this code generates the error, but sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Replace the last two lines with `for g in Enemies:` / `print(g.name)`.  You need to print the name from the objects you created, not from the class itself.

Comment: It generated the error when I realized that having:
random_name = random.randint(1,10)
 at the start of the code (which means it was executed only once in the entire code) made every Goblin have the same name and decided to try and generate the name at the start of the loop

Comment: Oh, Tim Robert's answer worked!

Comment: Your last loop should simply be: `for enemy in Enemies: print(enemy.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't produce the same error you posted, getting instead:

```py
>>> enemy_spawner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in enemy_spawner
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

That's expected though, because while your structure is good it's missing a key bit of boilerplate to make it work -- you need to pass the list of arguments down to the superclass's constructor. Try this instead:

```py
class Goblin(Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or indeed simply omit the `__init__` method entirely!

```py
class Goblin(Entity):
    pass
```

Also: to do the printing, you'll have to reference the Goblin instance instead of the Goblin class.

```py
for enemy in Enemies:
    print(enemy.name)
```

---

Might I suggest a different way, though? Consider building a constructor inside `Entity` that produces a Goblin with a random name!

```py
class Entity:

    # As above
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.min_hp = min_hp
        attack_dmg = attack_dmg

    # this is new!
    @classmethod
    def with_random_name(cls, name_generator=some_name_generator_function, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls(name=name_generator(), *args, **kwargs)

# Set some default values if all goblins should be the same
class Goblin(Entity)
    min_hp, max_hp = 5, 10  # or whatever
    attack_damage = 2       # or whatever
    
    def __init__(self, name, min_hp, max_hp, attack_damage, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,
            min_hp=self.min_hp,
            max_hp=self.max_hp,
            attack_damage=self.attack_damage,
            **kwargs)
```

This will let you do:

```py
for _ in range(num_enemies):
    enemy = Goblin.with_random_name()
    enemies.append(enemy)
```

Comment: You're amazing, thank you so much! Seeing a better way of writing something I wrote is extremely useful for learning, and I hope this answer helps anyone who tries to do enemy generation and things like that.

Comment: @kouketsu writing classmethods for alternate constructors is useful in a TON of situations. Imagine your game object -- you'll want to init it fresh, of course, but also at some point maybe you have save data written to disk that you want to load from. Rather than init'ing a blank object and calling some load function on it, write an alternate `from_save_data` constructor in `Game` that is given either the file itself (and it has to do the I/O) or preferably just a stream of data so you can easily pull from file, network socket, or raw string.

Comment: As much as I liked this comment I understood very little, I still haven't learned about constructors, etc. I did this enemy generator after learning about the basics of OOP

Comment: @kouketsu no worries -- `__init__` is a constructor (sort of, it's an initializer, but in Python you can consider them the same thing in 99% of circumstances and I am using them synonymously here). `with_random_name` is then an _alternate_ constructor, meaning it's another code path to create an instance of a class.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for taking the time to explain something that seems so simple (simple for good programmers), you helped me learn a lot, and now I know more stuff to research (learn about constructors, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `*args` to `__init__`. And also just getting the `name` attribute from the actual values from the `Enemies` list:

```
import random

max_enemies = 5


class Entity():
    def __init__(self, name, max_hp=None, min_hp=None, attack_dmg=None):
        self.name = name
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.min_hp = min_hp
        attack_dmg = attack_dmg

class Goblin(Entity):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)


Enemies = []




def enemy_spawner():
    for x in range(max_enemies):
        random_name_gen = random.randint(1, 10)
        Enemies.append(Goblin(random_name_gen))

enemy_spawner()

for x in Enemies:
    print(x.name)
```

Example output:

```
10
9
9
6
2
```